# Quantum flag manifolds

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation

What are quantum flag manifolds?
Please introduce me a good reference for to learn them.
I no nothing about flag manifolds and I need an introductory text book related to this subject. If someone knows how and from where can I enter to it? please leave me a comment.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't recall these discussed round here, but, perhaps you might sift through the various items posted in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/575230/36530 also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantum+flag+manifold

Comment: also perhaps http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-abs_connect

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, but I need a book or an introductory paper.

Comment: You might try asking this on Math Overflow. It might be an agreeable question